# Find unique/duplicated rows from has and belongs to many association

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, unique

I have following DB structure:

Table **cars**:

```
+----+-----------------------+
| id | few other columns.... |
+----+-----------------------+
|  1 | ...                   |
|  2 | ...                   |
|  3 | ...                   |
+----+-----------------------+
```

Table **properties**:

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | title |
|  2 | type  |
|  3 | brand |
|  4 | color |
+----+-------+
```

Table **cars_properties**:

```
+----+--------+-------------+------------+
| id | car_id | property_id |    txt     |
+----+--------+-------------+------------+
|  1 |      1 |           1 | Volvo V70  |
|  2 |      1 |           2 | personal   |
|  3 |      1 |           3 | Volvo      |
|  4 |      1 |           4 | white      |
|  5 |      2 |           1 | Volvo VV   |
|  6 |      2 |           2 | personal   |
|  7 |      2 |           3 | Volvo      |
|  8 |      2 |           4 | blue       |
|  9 |      3 |           1 | Volvo XXL  |
| 10 |      3 |           2 | truck      |
| 11 |      3 |           3 | Volvo      |
| 12 |      3 |           4 | white      |
+----+--------+-------------+------------+
```

I would like to get all cars that have unique/duplicated values in one or many properties. Currently I'm using this SQL pattern to get duplicates for car type and brand:

```
SELECT cars.id FROM cars
  LEFT JOIN cars_properties AS cp_0 ON cp_0.car_id = cars.id AND cp_0.property_id = 2 # => type
  LEFT JOIN cars_properties AS cp_1 ON cp_1.car_id = cars.id AND cp_1.property_id = 3 # => brand
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT cp_0.txt AS type_txt, cp_1.txt AS brand_txt FROM cars 
    LEFT JOIN cars_properties AS cp_0 ON cp_0.car_id = cars.id AND cp_0.property_id = 2 
    LEFT JOIN cars_properties AS cp_1 ON cp_1.car_id = cars.id AND cp_1.property_id = 3 
    GROUP BY cp_0.txt, cp_1.txt 
    HAVING COUNT(cars.id) > 1
  ) dupes ON cp_0.txt=dupes.type_txt AND cp_1.txt=dupes.brand_txt;
```

And expected result is:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
+----+
```

Explanation: Both cars with id = 1 and 2 has `type` and `brand` that is present in more than one car (*multiple times*).

As for unique cars, I'm just altering: `HAVING COUNT(cars.id) = 1` and I want to find all rows where the combination of properties is present only in one car (*once*).

It works fine, but it's extremely slow with more than 2 properties I want to check. 
I cannot change the DB structure, and I'm not sure how to optimize the query, or if there are better ways of achieving this.

It feels like I would need to implement counter table, where each property id and value (txt) would also store corresponding number of occurrences in cars, and update this counter on every insert/update/delete... But I still hope there is some better SQL, that could help. Do you know some? Any advice greatly appreciated, thanks!

PS: I tried to create fiddle for it, but after I build schema I cannot run any SQL on it. To quickly setup DB with data, you can check [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/967bc)

Comment: `... all cars that have unique/duplicated values` The purpose is not clear. Either they are unique, or they are duplicate (or they don't exist at all)

Comment: Could you please give your expected output  based on your data?

Comment: I think you have a structural problem. It makes more sense for the field `txt` to be in the `cars_properties` table.

Comment: @joop It depends on what user wants to see (unique/duplicates). I just need to offer solution to both.

Comment: @mikeyq6 It doesn't. Maybe in this example, but imagine there are properties that only certain cars have, while others not... Do you get what I mean?

Comment: @lp1051 Ok. But then the `cars` table should be renamed `cars_state`, as the only information it has is about the state of the car, and this information is duplicated.

Comment: @Utstav - added expected result and explanation

Comment: @mikeyq6 I included `state` field there just to illustrate that in cars table can be other fields as well (for example: `owner_id`,`created`, `updated`...). But my question is not about DB design, it's something I cannot change. The only thing I can do is to add new tables, like the mentioned *counter table*.